# Why value not setting to a column in pandas dataframe with loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with modified dataset of [Donors Choose](https://www.kaggle.com/donorschoose/io) dataset. I am trying to do response coding for categorical variables. I am trying to set value to a new column using loc. The value only gets set for criteria when project_is_approved value is 1 and NOT the other time when its 0.

Take a look at below screen-shots

1. Initialize value to new column
   [image: new column and datatypes]
2. Picking all unique value in train dataset and updating the row value for specific columns `school_state_0` and `school_state_1` based on whether `project_is_approved` or not
   [image: loc functionality not working]

Couple of more example for more understanding where value is getting calulcated, but not getting set.
[image: more example]

Head for original dataset
[image: original dataset]
Please let me know if you need anymore information regarding the issue.

Comment: One idea, how working if remove `[]` from `["school_state_0"]` and `["school_state_1"]` ?

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for your suggestion. I resolved it, look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the additional `is_project_approved` when setting the value, resolve the issue

Here is the code
[image: working code]

Answer (score 0):

From the code, it looks like each row will only either set `school_state_0` value or `school_state_1` value; because each row can only either have `project_approved` as 0 or 1.

I dont think the output you have is incorrect.